# Interview Question: Optimise a function that can find the amount of numbers that contain x or y in a given range, but not both?

Tags: java, algorithm, optimization

The question goes like this:
Can you write a method that can find the amount of numbers which contain 6 or 8. Numbers which contain both digits shouldn't be counted. E.g

> 3628

Is not a valid number 
, but

> 3528

Is

Initially I thought about converting the number to a string and checking if it contained either but not both digits. Eventually I came up with something like this. I thought that by using arithmetic operations the computation would be faster. This code passed 4 out of 6 test cases. However there was a time limit of two seconds and the last two test cases had their range in 52 and 64 bit integers, which made the computation take longer and is the reason I'm using `long`. I thought about it but couldn't think of a more efficient solution. Can you optimise the problem further? Is it possible to fit into the 2 second time limit?

```
    public static long countNums(int start, int end) {
    long nums = 0;

    for (long i = start; i < end; i++) {

        boolean six = false;
        boolean eight = false;
        long curr = i;

        while (curr != 0) {

            if (curr % 10 == 6) {
                six = true;
            }
            if (curr % 10 == 8) {
                eight = true;
            }
            if (six && eight) {
                break;
            }
            curr /= 10;
        }

        if ((six && !eight) || (eight && !six)) {
            nums++;
        }

    }

    return nums;
}
```

Comment: Sounds quite FIZZBUZZy to me. Although the 2 second requirement is interesting. If you don’t know what FIZZBUZZ is, look it up and try a few of the many solutions to it and see if any fit your 2 second requirement. Did the potential employer tell you what hardware this program would be running on? Lol... have fun!!

Comment: *The question goes like this: Can you write a method that can find the amount of numbers which contain 6 or 8.* **Yes**. When do I start?

Comment: `(curr % 6) == 0` should probably be `(curr % 10) == 6`

Comment: You are absolutely correct, edited my post.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a number of ideas presented in the various answers to this question which would certainly make it possible to solve the problem using a very small amount of CPU time. We can put them together to produce an extremely efficient solution, whose time complexity is linear in the length of the (larger) argument.

We can start with a few observations.

First, as with any problem requiring the count of integers in an interval which satisfy some predicate P, we can simplify the problem using half-open intervals [Note 1] and the identity:

```
Count(P, [lo, hi) ) = Count(P, [0, hi) ) - Count(P, [0, lo) )
```

so that we only need to consider intervals starting at 0.

Second, in this particular problem we can also assume that `hi` and `lo` are the same length (in digits), since `lo` can be written with leading zeros. That's possible because `0` is not a "special" digit, so adding a `0` to the beginning of a number does not change the truth value of the predicate.

Third, since here we are dealing with two different predicates ("contains a 6" and "contains an 8"), it is useful to remember the inclusion/exclusion principle:

```
Count(P or Q) = Count(P) + Count(Q) - Count(P and Q)
```

as well as the "exclusive or" principle:

```
Count(P xor Q) = Count(P or Q) - Count(P and Q)
```

[Note 2]

With that behind us, let's start by solving the counting problem for intervals  consisting of all (zero-padded if necessary) numbers of a given length `n`: `Count(P, [0, 10n) )`.

That's quite easy to compute. We start with some simpler counting problems over that interval. We'll start with the predicates `Has6` and `Has8`, which are true for numbers whose decimal expansion includes a 6 or an 8, respectively. We know that there are exactly 10<sup>n</sup> integers in the interval. If we exclude a digit value, (`6` or `8`), then we are left with 9 possible digits in each position resulting in a count of 9<sup>n</sup>. Thus, `Count(Has6)` and `Count(Has8)` are both 10<sup>n</sup> − 9<sup>n</sup>.

In the same way, we can compute `Count(Has6 or Has8)` as 10<sup>n</sup> − 8<sup>n</sup>, since when we list numbers having neither a 6 nor an 8, there are only 8 possible digits in each position (8<sup>n</sup> possibilities) and the remaining numbers have a 6 or an 8 or both.

With that, we can use the inclusion/exclusion principle to compute:

`Count(Has6 and Has8) = Count(Has6) + Count(Has8) - Count(Has6 or Has8)`

and therefore

```
Count(Has6 xor Has8) = Count(Has6 or Has8) − Count(Has6 and Has8)
                    = Count(Has6 or Has8) − (Count(Has6) + Count(Has8) - Count(Has6 or Has8))
                    = 2 * Count(Has6 or Has8) − 2 * Count(Has6)
                    = 2 * ((10n − 8n) − (10n − 9n))
                    = 2 * (9n − 8n)
```

With that remarkably simple formula, we can proceed to compute the count for intervals over any range starting at 0. Suppose we have the range `[0, ab...)` where `a` and `b` are digits. We can split that into `a` ranges:

```
[00000, 10000)
[10000, 20000)
...
[(a-1)0000, a0000)
[a0000, ab...)
```

For the first set of ranges, there are two possibilities. If the first digit is neither 6 nor 8, then it can be ignored and the count can be computed over the remaining `n-1` digits using the formula above, 2 * (9<sup>n−1</sup> − 8<sup>n−1</sup>). On the other hand, if the first digit is either 6 or 8, then the count for that range is 9<sup>n−1</sup>, since all integers which *do not* contain the other special digit are counted.

For the last range, we also have two possibilities. If `a` is not special, we can just ignore it and add the count for the interval `[0000, b000)` (conceptually using a recursive call). If `a` is special, then we need to compute the number of integers in `[0000, b000)` which do not have the other special digit, which we can do by using a similar one-digit-at-a-time algorithm (show below).

In pseudocode:

```
count(lo, hi):
  Return count_to(hi) - count_to(lo).

count_to(hi):
  Let n be the number of digits in hi.
  If n is 0, return 0.
  Let d be the first digit of hi.
  Let rest be the rest of hi (without its first digit).
  If d is 0, 1, 2, 3, 4 or 5:
    Return d * 2 * (9 ** (n - 1) - 8 ** (n - 1))
           + count_to(rest).
  If d is 7:
    Return 6 * 2 * (9 ** (n - 1) - 8 ** (n - 1))
           + 9 ** (n - 1) 
           + count_to(rest).
  If d is 9:
    Return 7 * 2 * (9 ** (n - 1) - 8 ** (n - 1))
           + 2 * 9 ** (n - 1) 
           + count_to(rest).
  If d is 6:
    Return 6 * 2 * (9 ** (n - 1) - 8 ** (n - 1))
           + count_without(rest, 8).
  If d is 8:
    Return 7 * 2 * (9 ** (n - 1) - 8 ** (n - 1))
           + 9 ** (n - 1) 
           + count_without(rest, 6).

count_without(hi, avoid):
  Let n be the number of digits in hi.
  If n is 0, return 0.
  Let d be the first digit of hi.
  Let rest be the rest of hi (without its first digit).
  If d is less than avoid:
    Return d * 9 ** (n - 1)
           + count_without(rest, avoid)
  If d is equal to avoid:
    Return d * 9 ** (n - 1)
  If d is greater than avoid:
    Return (d - 1) * 9 ** (n - 1)
           + count_without(rest, avoid)
```

Since the recursive calls can all be turned into tail calls using an accumulator argument, we can turn the recursion into a simple loop over the digits in the original number. Or, better said, two loops: one which loops over the prefix not containing any special digit, and the second one which starts when a special digit is found and loops over the rest of the number avoiding the other special digit.

Here's a somewhat tested implementation in C:

```
/* The following were generated with a little C program, not included. */
static const unsigned maxPow10 = 20;
static const unsigned long long pow8[] = {
                     1ULL,                    8ULL,                   64ULL,                  512ULL,                 4096ULL,
                 32768ULL,               262144ULL,              2097152ULL,             16777216ULL,            134217728ULL,
            1073741824ULL,           8589934592ULL,          68719476736ULL,         549755813888ULL,        4398046511104ULL,
        35184372088832ULL,      281474976710656ULL,     2251799813685248ULL,    18014398509481984ULL,   144115188075855872ULL
};
static const unsigned long long pow9[] = {
                     1ULL,                    9ULL,                   81ULL,                  729ULL,                 6561ULL,
                 59049ULL,               531441ULL,              4782969ULL,             43046721ULL,            387420489ULL,
            3486784401ULL,          31381059609ULL,         282429536481ULL,        2541865828329ULL,       22876792454961ULL,
       205891132094649ULL,     1853020188851841ULL,    16677181699666569ULL,   150094635296999121ULL,  1350851717672992089ULL
};  
static const unsigned long long pow10[] = {
                     1ULL,                   10ULL,                  100ULL,                 1000ULL,                10000ULL,
                100000ULL,              1000000ULL,             10000000ULL,            100000000ULL,           1000000000ULL,
           10000000000ULL,         100000000000ULL,        1000000000000ULL,       10000000000000ULL,      100000000000000ULL,
      1000000000000000ULL,    10000000000000000ULL,   100000000000000000ULL,  1000000000000000000ULL, 10000000000000000000ULL
};            

/* Return the number of integers in the range [0, lim % 10**n) which
 * do not have the digit avoid in their decimal representation.
 * (lim % 10**n is the last n digits of lim).
 */
static unsigned long long countWithout(unsigned long long lim, int n, int avoid) {
  unsigned long long count = 0;
  while (n) {
    /* isolate the nth last digit of lim and decrement n */
    unsigned digit = lim / pow10[--n] % 10;
    /* For each starting digit less than digit except avoid,
     * add 9**n qualifying integers. If the avoided digit is
     * encountered, stop.
     */
    count += (digit <= avoid ? digit : digit - 1) * pow9[n];
    if (digit == avoid) break;
  }
  return count;
}

static unsigned long long countTo(unsigned long long lim) {
  unsigned long long count = 0;
  unsigned n = maxPow10;
  /* Loop over the digits in lim until a 6 or an 8 is encountered or all of the
   * digits have been processed. For each digit position, add the appropriate
   * number of qualifying numbers which start with a smaller digit, using either
   * the xor formula 2 * (9**n - 8**n) or the exclusion formula 9**n, depending
   * on whether the starting digit is special or not. Once a special digit is
   * encountered, use countWithout to process the rest of the digits.
   */
  while (n) {
    unsigned digit = lim / pow10[--n] % 10;
    switch (digit) {
      default:count += digit * (2 * (pow9[n] - pow8[n]));
              break;
      case 6: count += 6 * (2 * (pow9[n] - pow8[n]));
              return count + countWithout(lim, n, 8);
      case 7: count += 6 * (2 * (pow9[n] - pow8[n])) + pow9[n];
              break;
      case 8: count += 7 * (2 * (pow9[n] - pow8[n])) + pow9[n];
              return count + countWithout(lim, n, 6);
      case 9: count += 7 * (2 * (pow9[n] - pow8[n])) + 2 * pow9[n];
              break;
    }
  }
  return count;
}

unsigned long long countBetween(unsigned long long lo, unsigned long long hi) {
  return hi > lo ? countTo(hi) - countTo(lo) : 0;
}
```

#### Notes

1. If we needed to count in a closed interval, we might try to use another obvious identity:

   ```
   Count(P, [lo, hi] ) = Count(P, [lo, hi + 1) )
   ```

   However, since `hi + 1` would overflow if `hi` were the largest representable integer, we would be better off computing `Count( [lo, hi) )` and then adding 1 if `hi` satisfies the predicate.
2. Putting those two together gives us:

   ```
   Count(P xor Q) = Count(P) + Count(Q) - 2*Count(P and Q)
   ```

   which is interesting but not directly useful in this problem.

Comment: The variable `digit` in function count_without is variable `d`?

Comment: @hk6279: yes. I'll fix that. Thanks

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, and to everyone who contributed towards it. I am coding it in Java, and so far it looks promising. It is fair to say, that I would have never solved this on my own within the 30 min time limit during the interview. I can post the solution later when I'm done.

Comment: @moe: i wrote the proof of concept in C; I can add it if you like. I used pseudocode in the answer because I don't do Java and the C code might be a bit hard to follow.

Comment: @rici: Yes, please :)

Comment: @Moe: OK, added. I put some comments in but didn't clean it up much.

Answer (score 2):

Don't count. Calculate!

Let's say you needed to figure out how many 5-digit numbers contain exactly one of `6` or `8`.

Different ways of looking at it, but here's one. For a 5-digit number, there are 5 positions where that `6` or `8` digit could be. There are two choice of which digit is on that position. For all other positions there are 8 possible digits to choose from, i.e. 0-5,7,9, except for first position which cannot be `0` (wouldn't be a 5 digit number if it was).

If special digit is in first position: `2 * 8 * 8 * 8 * 8` = `8192`.

Otherwise: `4 * 2 * 7 * 8 * 8 * 8` = `28672`

Added together: `8192 + 28672` = **`36864`**

---

That was an example of how to calculate with lots of digits. With few digits you might count and still stay without time limit, if you choose.

Now, if range is something like `39` - `5427`, you can split that into multiple ranges that can be calculated like above, e.g. `39`-`99` (count), `100`-`999` (calc), `1000`-`4999` (calc), `5000`-`5399` (calc), `5400`-`5427` (count).

Now you need to code all that. Good luck!

Comment: This is nasty.  Consider that your range may not begin or end evenly on a five digit number.  The range could be something like 12345 to 54321.  About half of the number digits will be missing.  Maybe it could be coded with strings or something, but as an interview question it's pretty unfair.

Comment: That's a **nasty problem** for a **job interview question.**

Comment: @markspace Are you commenting on the question, or my **optimized** answer? A good job interview question will find people that can think outside the box for the best solution, rather than only going for brute-force solutions.

Comment: On both, I guess.  If this is the best optimized solution, then I think it's quite unfair to expect a candidate to code this up and get it passing a series of tests in a job interview.  Let's just say I probably would not want to work there.  As a theoretical discussion, it's fine, but all the fiddly details (which I notice you did not actually solve) are pretty darn fiddly and would exceed what I consider a reasonable job interview question.

Comment: Multiple occurrences of either 6 or 8 are fine. Eg in the Range 60-70 the program would return 9.

Comment: @markspace I think, given that x and y is a single digit, Andreas' solution could be generalized without a severe challenge. In the given number N, each digit d(i) has a set of alphabets that could be used and that may or may not include x or y. Moreover, I guess that this problem is a sort of counting problem that many CS student would know well about. Only that if x or y has multiple digits AND all the digits in x (or y) are the same (e.g. 666, 33, 444, 77777), then, Andreas' algorithm would not work as beautifully as it did otherwise.

Comment: @markspace I guess you are right. I was mistaken in my previous comment but could not delete it, which I do not know why.

Comment: @Stephen I was thinking the same way at first, but the more you turn it around in your head the more convoluted it becomes.  As anything other than theoretical discussion it's really mean.  Maybe there's a recurrence relation that could be used to solve the digit counting problem, but it's been too long since school for me, and honestly I don't think I've needed to solve one single recurrence problem since then.

Comment: @markspace: if you turn it over in your head enough, it (mostly) unconvolutes, although a switch statement will prove to be useful. The trick is to first use fgb's technique so that only intervals starting at 0 need to be solved, and then to break every interval into up to 10 smaller intervals, each of which with a different first digit, of which all but the last are "complete". I wrote that at much greater length as an answer. Personally, I think this is a good interview question because it allows you to see how the candidate approaches the problem, and there are various reasonable answers.

Comment: @rici  I still have to disagree (sorry about that).  This problem was posted yesterday, how long have you been working on your solution?  A job interview question probably has 20 to 40 minutes to solve the problem.  Taking 24 hours to solve it and then declaring it "a good interview question" seems a little off to me.

Comment: @markspace: I was on a bus all day yesterday, and I didn't see it until today. And it took me a *lot* longer to write up the explanation of the answer than to figure it out and code a POC, since I had other things to do today. I don't claim my answer would be necessary to pass an interview; as an interviewer I would be happy with many other answers. However, it is always nice when there is an answer that an extraordinary candidate might come up with, as well as the acceptable ones.

Comment: I had 30 minutes to solve that question, without any external help whatsoever. The recruiter was constantly watching behind my back as I attempted to code it out. It is fair to say that I would have never reached an efficient solution within this time limit. Surprisingly I have a second interview with the company next week. If you are interested I will let you know If I got a job offer.

Answer (score 2):

To make it a bit easier, you only need the ending number, then the starting number can be assumed to be `0`. Then `countNums(start, end)` is the same as `countNums(end) - countNums(start - 1)`.

This can be done recursively. Define a function like:

```
countNums(String end, boolean usedSix, boolean usedEight)
```

Then go through each possible digit for the first number, then make a recursive call to get the remaining digits.

`end` would be one digit shorter each time until you get to the empty string. For `854`, `end` would become `99` for the digits `0` to `7`, then `54` for the number `8`. Update `usedSix` or `usedEight` when these numbers are added. When `end` is empty, return `1` or `0` based on `usedSix` and `usedEight`. Add up all the results to get the total.

Also, all the digits other than `6` or `8` are equivalent, so you can save calculating the count for numbers beginning with each of them, and only calculate once, then multiply the result.

These recursive solutions can be optimised by using memoization to store the results of previous calls, so that they don't need to be calculated multiple times.

Comment: Shouldn't it be countNums(end) - countNums(start **- 1**)? E.g. count from 6 to 9 is 2. But countNums(9) - countNums(6) = 2 - 1 = 1.

Answer (score 2):

Two seconds are a pretty generous limit for numbers fitting in a `long` as it's

---

Let's start by computing the counts for half-closed ranges of the form `[x * 10**n, (x+1) * 10**n)`, i.e., allowing all combinations of `n` digits after a prefix `x`. For example, with `x=124` and `n=2`, we have the set of all numbers of the form `124??`.

Let's call this count `f(x, n)`. We have

```
f(x, n) = f6(x, n) + f8(x, n) - f68(x, n)
```

where `f6` and `f8` denote the counts of numbers in this range containing a the digits "6" and "8", respectively, and `f68` denote the counts of such numbers containing both of them.

We have `f6(x, 0)` equals to one if `x` contains the digit `6`, and zero otherwise. The initial conditions for the other functions are analogous.

We have

```
f6(x, n+1) = 10 ** n + 9 * f6(x, n)
```

as we can append either the "6" or any of the remaining nine digits. Analogously for `f8`. We also have

```
f68(x, n+1) = f6(x, n) + f8(x, n) + 8 * f68(x, x)
```

as we can append the "8", the "6" or any of the eight remaining digits.

Assuming sane values (e.g., no more than 20 digits), this computation can be performed by filling a table using pencil and paper in a few minutes.
The complexity is linear in the number of digits.

---

For a general range, we need to split it into ranges of the above form.
Let's take the range 12345 to 54321 as an example. We split it as

```
12345
12346
...
12349

1235?
1236?
...
1239?

124??
125??
...
129??

13???
14???
...
19???

2????
3????
4????

50???
51???
52???
53???

540??
541??
542??

5430?
5431?

54320
54321
```

where the question marks denote arbitrary digits. These are disjoint ranges of the above form, so the result is the sum `f(12345, 0) + f(12346, 0) + ... + f(1235, 1) + ... + f(54321, 0)`.

In general, the number of generated intervals is linear in the number of digits, so the overall complexity is quadratic.